# How use this session->set_userdata in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have some promblem with CI when i use $this->session->set_userdata

Controller

```
<?php

Class Auth extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->Model('Model_pengguna');
        $this->load->Model('Model_guru');
        $this->load->Model('Model_siswa');
    }

    function index(){
        $this->load->view('auth/login');
    }

    function chek_login() {
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $login_pengguna = $this->Model_pengguna->chek_login($username, $password);
            $login_guru = $this->Model_guru->chek_login($username, $password);
            $login_siswa = $this->Model_siswa->chek_login($username, $password);

            if (!empty($login_pengguna)) {
                //success login for user
                $this->session->set_userdata($login_pengguna);
                redirect('Admin/Dashboard');
            } elseif (!empty($login_guru)) {
                $this->session->set_userdata($login_guru);
                redirect('Admin/Dashboard');
            } elseif (!empty($login_siswa)) {
                $this->session->set_userdata($login_siswa);
                redirect('Admin/Dashboard');
            } else {
                redirect('Auth');
            }
        }
    }

    function Logout() {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('Auth');
    }

}

?>
```

I try to get in here, to get a session data

Model Pengguna

```
<?php
Class Model_pengguna extends CI_Model{
    
    
    function chek_login($username,$password){
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $this->db->where('password',$password);
        $pengguna=$this->db->get('pengguna')->row_Array();
        return $pengguna;
    }
}
?>
```

Model Guru

```
<?php

Class Model_guru extends CI_Model {

    function chek_login($username, $password) {
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $guru = $this->db->get('guru')->row_Array();
        return $guru;
    }

    function add($uploads) {
        $data = array(
            'nama'     => $this->input->post('nama'),
            'nik'      => $this->input->post('nik'),
            'alamat'   => $this->input->post('alamat'),
            'foto'     => $uploads,
            'username' => $this->input->post('nik'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('nik'),
            'level'=>2,
        );
        $this->db->insert('guru',$data);
    }
    
    
    function edit(){
        $data=array(
            'nama'=> $this->input->post('nama'),
            'alamat'=>$this->input->post('alamat'),
        );
       $nik=$this->input->post('nik');
       $this->db->where('nik',$nik);
       $this->db->update('guru',$data);
    }

}
?>
```

model siswa

```
<?php

Class Model_siswa extends CI_Model {

    function chek_login($username, $password) {
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $siswa= $this->db->get('siswa')->row_Array();
        return $siswa;
    }
    
    function add($uploads){
        $data=array(
            'nama'         => $this->input->post('nama'),
            'alamat'       => $this->input->post('alamat'),
            'nis'          => $this->input->post('nis'),
            'nik'          => $this->input->post('nik'),
            'foto'         => $uploads,
            'username'     => $this->input->post('nis'),
            'password'     => $this->input->post('nis'),
            'level'=>3,
            'no_hp_ortu'   => $this->input->post('no_hp_ortu'),
            'kelas'        => $this->input->post('kelas'),
            );
            $this->db->insert('siswa',$data);
            
    }
    function edit(){
        $data=array(
            'nama'         => $this->input->post('nama'),
            'alamat'       => $this->input->post('alamat'),
            'no_hp_ortu'   => $this->input->post('no_hp_ortu'),
            'nik'          => $this->input->post('nik'),
        );
        
        $nis= $this->input->post('nis');
        $this->db->where('nis',$nis);
        $this->db->update('siswa',$data);
        
    }

}
?>
```

My problem is i just can get email and level id from array in session

How to solved that?

Comment: There are a bunch of typos in your code, but I think this is what you're after:   $pengguna=$this->db->get('pengguna')->row_Array().  The row_array() method needs to be all lower case.